# No natural transformation

Tags: category-theory

> **2.19** Let $\mathcal B$ be the category of finite sets and bijections. For $X\in\mathcal B$, let $\mathbf{Sym}(X)$ be the set of bijections $X\to X$ and let $\mathbf{Ord}(X)$ be the set of total orders on $X$.
>
> a. Give a definition of $\bf Sym$ on morphisms of $\mathcal B$ so that $\bf Sym$ becomes a functor $\mathcal B\to\bf Set$. Do the same for $\bf Ord$. (Both your definitions should be canonical. This means, roughly, that you should not use the word 'choose'.)
>   b. Show that there is no natural transformation $\mathbf{Sym}\to\bf Ord$. (Hint: consider the identity permutation.)
>
> Conclude that $\mathbf{Sym}(X)\cong\mathbf{Ord}(X)$ for all $X\in\mathcal B$, but not naturally in $X\in\mathcal B$.

I'm having trouble with part b. Intuitively, it is clear that there is no canonical way of assigning a permutation of $X$ onto an ordering of $X$, but I've failed to prove it rigorously thus far.

Please give me a hint.

Comment: Dear iwriteonbananas, don't you think that you should at least put a reference to the textbook you are so shamelessly copying from?

Comment: Sorry, I agree. I got it from the lecture notes http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/ct/two.pdf (page 22)

Comment: That's better !

Comment: That exercise also appears in Tom Leinster's book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that there exists a natural transformation $\alpha : {\bf Sym} \to {\bf Ord}$, draw its naturality diagram, and apply it to the identity permutation over a simple set like $B = \{ 0, 1 \}$.

Let $f : B \to B$ be defined by $f(0) = 1$, $f(1) = 0$. Look at $\alpha_B \circ {\bf Sym}(f)$ and ${\bf Ord}(f) \circ \alpha_B$ applied to the identity permutation on $B$.